# When I use createElement and set it's text, I can't see it on `View Source`

Tags: javascript, json, angular, schema

```
private addStructuredData(el: ElementRef, schema: JsonLdSchemas) {
    const script = this.renderer.createElement('script');
    this.renderer.setAttribute(script, 'type', 'application/ld+json');
    script.text = JSON.stringify(schema);
    this.renderer.appendChild(el.nativeElement, script);
}
```

I have the above code as an Angular function. The idea is to create a script element then append it as a child to whichever element is passed in the function.

This function works well if you only want to see the result through `Inspect Element`. The schema appears perfectly there.

Though when I try to view it through `View Source`, the schema doesn't appear. Any Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's expected. When you view the source of a page, you will be viewing the raw uncompressed response that the server sent you. It will *not* contain any modifications that may have been made by scripts to the DOM.

The changes *will* be viewable by inspecting the element in developer tools, or by examining the `innerHTML` / `outerHTML` of the element or one of its ancestors.

In your case, either the source or one of the scripts it requires will have the script text that appends the new script, in Javascript, eg, something like

```
addStructuredData(el, schema) {
    const script = this.renderer.createElement('script');
    this.renderer.setAttribute(script, 'type', 'application/ld+json');
    script.text = JSON.stringify(schema);
    this.renderer.appendChild(el.nativeElement, script);
}
```

(or perhaps converted into ES5 rather than ES6)

But the script that the above appends will *not* be visible by looking at the `view-source` of your page.

Comment: This worked before though. And it works as well when I remove this part 
`script.text = JSON.stringify(schema);` 
Any idea why that is?

Comment: That doesn't make sense, are you sure? Dynamically created elements via Javascript are done on the client, not the server. Changing the JS should only result in the source text of that Javascript changing, but not in anything else.

Comment: Yes, this was working before. Please note that I'm using Renderer2 (https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) Sorry. Forgot to say this above which I believe is an important info.